# Fabric Multiple Orderer Service

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Trying to create multiple orderers on the same network, but am getting

> Could not connect to {peer0.org1.example.com:11051 [] []
>   peer0.org1.example.com:11051 } : context deadline exceeded

Can anyone provide me sample configuration for multiple orderers in sample network?

Comment: The error above appears to have nothing to do with orderers.  Can you be more specific on what you are actually trying to do (perhaps share your config) and post more of the error trace/log?

Comment: @GariSingh I have a more general question which I cannot find the answer in any online resources. Is it possible to have multiple (lets say two), orderers in the same network (same org) and connect them to Kafka cluster for management. So in case one of them goes down, the other one becomes the leader?